# parsing CSV files with escaped characters in PHP

Tags: php, csv, escaping, google-docs

I'm trying to use a Google Docs spreadsheet as a database for a very simple project, and I feel I have a working version now, based on yc's answer for this question:
[using Google Docs as a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037223/using-google-docs-as-a-database)

My problem is that now I arrived where I might need to do something with the escaped characters. I don't know if there is a standard implementation for CSV or it's different from program to program, but here is what Google Docs is doing:

If I have the following source data (a,b,c,d,e meaning 5 separate columns)

```
a     b     c     d1, d2, d3, d4     e1, e2, "e3, e4", e5, "e6"
```

Then it produces the following line:

```
a,b,c,"d1, d2, d3, d4","e1, e2, ""e3, e4"", e5, ""e6"""
```

As far as I understand, it wraps the whole field in "field" if it finds something and escapes the " as "". Maybe we just need to unescape "" into " and unwrap the field from "field" into field.

Is there any way to parse this version of CSV in PHP? If it's really hard, I still have an idea how to replace the characters inside Google Docs, and publish them on a different sheet, but I hope it is possible to solve it in a simple PHP function.

*Alternative solution:* maybe it's much easier to just fetch the XML in RSS or ATOM format, but I don't know how to parse those formats.

Comment: are you able to restrict the input of data into the google doc spreadsheet? you can do `preg_replace` for the escape char, but from your code we can't really tell what exactly are returned from the google doc.

Comment: Do you mean, that if its mine or from a 3rd party source? Yes, its mine I use it as some kind of minimal database.

Comment: I can't tell either how does the escaping work for Google Docs. But it seems like that if there is any comma in the field, it puts a " " around the whole field. And if there is any ", it escapes it with "".

Comment: @zsero i've done a project similar to yours in december...if i remember correctly you are using YQL as the "hook" right?  Are you inserting data manually?

Comment: @kjy112 No, finally I've settled down on pure server side PHP with no JS. But it doesn't seem to be very hard, I think we just need to unescape "" to " and "field" to field.

Comment: @zsero are you in control of how the data are injected into google doc? because i've written a "parser" in JS that can eliminate escape string before injection so when you output from google doc it'll eliminate all these CVS problems.

Comment: @zsero the reason i asked how the data are injected is you can make sure `\r` `\n` `,` `\`` and `"` are convert into ascii value before injection, then when you query for the CSV you'll be able to parse it with minimal or no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), using the quote itself as an escape character, something like:

```
$array = str_getcsv($str, ',', '"', '"');
```

If you are parsing from a file or a network stream, also consider using [fgetcsv](http://th2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: Thank for this function it does just what I need. Small problem is that it needs PHP 5.3+, but luckily i could use one of the comments from the official page. http://th2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#88311